# Вопрос заключается в расшифровке шифра Цезаря

Tags: шифрование

Здравствуйте. Я новичок, и мне нужно расшифровать шифр Цезаря.
Вот такие условия:

Одним из самых древних и простых из подстановочных шифров является шифр Юлия Цезаря. В этом шифре каждая буква алфавита заменяется буквой, которая находится на N  позиций дальше в этом же алфавите. Например, если N=3, то открытому тексту на русском языке 
встреча завтра в то же время
соответствует шифрованный текст: 
    ефхучэг лгехуг е хс ки еуипв
Нужно расшифровать заданный текст методом прямого перебора возможных вариантов. Смещение неизвестно, поэтому для расшифровки нужно составить варианты текста со всеми параметрами сдвига.

Задача интересная, но меня смущает "Алфавит при этом считается циклическим, после буквы Я идет А". Речь идет о неком цикле который, в конце, будет уходить в начало. По определенному условию. но Как реализуется это программно? Можете, пожалуйста, мне подказать на примере?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал такое на C#.
Создал массив с алфавитом ('а', 'б', 'в', ...)
Текст который нужно зашифровать мы по символьно разбираем и сравниваем с нашим массивом. если например буква а, в массиве она у нас первая, то есть её число будет 0, буква б = 1, в = 2 и тд. длинна нашего цыкла равна длинне массива. Возьмем для примера слово "ава", получится "020". Я например смещал на 3 буквы вправо. Тогда из нашего "020" получится "353" (0+3 2+3 0+3). А "353"это у нас уже другие буквы в массиве, и получится зашифрованное слово "гег". Чтобы расшифровать, нужно просто там где у нас +3 поменять на -3. Только нужно дописать % потому что если у нас будет буква я, она же последняя, то +3 должно переходить опять в начало массива, так что берем наше "число которое получится"%"длинна массива". Думаю обьяснил доступно, если есть базовые знания C# то написание займет не более 30 минут. Если не получится, могу скинуть код.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Действительно, шарп я знаю, но нынче пишу на ЖС. И в нем ваша идея не сработала, но пришлось от нее оттолкнуться. И вот, к какому решению я пришел.

...
id = check(example[i], sdvig)
...


 if(alfavit[i] == element) { res = i - sdvig } 
 if(res < 0) { res = alfavit.length - (Math.abs(res)) }

;)

Answer (score 2):

Вы не указали язык реализации, поэтому показываю на Паскале

```
function AddChar(AChar: Char; AOffset: Integer): Char;
const
  CFirst = Ord('А');
  CLast = Ord('Я');
  CCount = CLast - CFirst + 1;
var
  LRes: Integer;
begin
  LRes := Ord(AChar) + AOffset;
  while LRes < CFirst do
    Inc(LRes, CCount);
  while LRes > CLast do
    Dec(LRes, CCount);
  Result := Chr(LRes);
end;
```

Или на JS

```
function addChar(AChar, AOffset) {
  var  CFirst = 'А'.charCodeAt(0);
  var CLast = 'Я'.charCodeAt(0);
  var CCount = CLast - CFirst + 1;

  var res = AChar.charCodeAt(0) + AOffset;
  while (res < CFirst)
    res += CCount;
  while (res > CLast)
    res -= CCount
  return String.fromCharCode(res);
}
```

Comment: Пишу в Java, JS, C#. Паскаль читаю что называется со словарем. Задачу уже решил, но с удовольствием посмотрел бы на ваш вариант, если напишите на одном из этих языков. Спасибо за ответ :)

Comment: Добавил реализацию на JS